# Как в PHP получить значение тега span?

Tags: php, html, javascript

Есть вот такая строка на javascript

```
tdnumbe.innerHTML='<span  id="nom['+z+']" Value="nomers['+kolsttes+']" ></span>';
```

Как в коде PHP получить её значение?

Comment: Нужно отправить её на сервер. Сделать выборку по id и взять содержимое.

Comment: @Ринат Давлетбаев, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.